# Line up Characters

Tags: c#, text, alignment

I have a combobox made up of two numbers; inches and millimetres. At the moment it is looking hideous. I am wondering if some of the gurus here have anyway of lining the character '|' or at least make it nicer?

[image]

A bit of background info, the number inches and millimetres are separate strings which I append together like so:

`Size(in) + " (In) | " + Size(mm) + " (mm)"`

Comment: Look at the record that needs the most space and count the characters. Write a method with a string and an int as parameter, then you count the amount of characters in the string and get the missing characters until you reach the int value (which is the count of characters of our biggest string so far) then you fill in blank spaces.

Comment: Are you using WPF for this combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.PadRight(i);` and `String.PadLeft(i);` where `i` is a nr. of spaces to "fill":

Example:

```
// Just to simplify a little, create vars:
var inches = Size(in) + " (In) ";
var mm = " + Size(mm) + " (mm)";

var formatted = inches.PadRight(15) + "|" + mm.PadLeft(15);
```

Example of output using 15 for the padding value (obviously, you can adjust this as needed):

```
43 inches      |         123 cm
445554 inches  |       12345 cm
```

Comment: I think you are missing some brackets, this is just going to give a constant for `" (In) | ".PadRight(10)` because `.` obviously has higher precedence over `+`

Comment: Will this actually align the pipe character, or will it just add padding around it? I can't test it out right now, but I'm curious if this works :)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the feedback. I had a mistake in there, so I've edited my answer slightly. This is cleaner and more clear - and yes, it works. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the cleanest way would be to format every number to have 3 decimal places for at least inches. This still won't be perfect however since the letter font width won't be perfect, to fix that you'd need to use a monospaced font.

To format to 3dp you can use the following

```
String.Format("{0:f3}", Size(in)) + " (In) | " + Size(mm) + " (mm)"
```

Since you have some values that are 2 digits before the decimal you can always use [`PadLeft`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to align these, but again this doesn't always work well without a monospaced font..

```
String.Format("{0:f3}", Size(in)).PadLeft(5, ' ') // or (5, '0')
```